# MASM arrays too long are truncated

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I need to declare a specific array having dimension equal to 208 and its values need to be declared at the begin:

```
array db 00110010b, 10100100b, ..., 011101110b
```

The problem is that I have to use 208 precise values and MASM doesn't accept declared arrays that are too long and truncates them.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S.
I have these 208 values stored elsewhere.

Regards

Comment: _"I have to use 208 precise values"_ Surely you don't have to put them all on one line? You could have e.g. 13 lines with 16 values per line.

Comment: MASM is running on DOS Box as a professor constraint.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with putting all the values on a single line.